# MVC with Observer and Observable

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

When using the MVC architecture and observable is model and View should be updated accordingly. What should be the observer? Controller or  View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture you are talking about is **MVVM(Model View View Model)**

Here if the model is changed it updates the **View**.

So there is no controller as such. View can be considered as the **Observer**.

**MVC** and **Observer** are different design pattern in a way, however view should be updated when the model changes.

So **View** can be considered as the observer and **Controller** as the observable.

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake So View can be considered as the observer and Controller as the observable

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake if you like the answer can you please accept it?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake By clicking the tick mark below the down arrow

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the "observable" (i.e., the subject) is the model. We are observing the subject and not the controller.
In summary:

- Model ≃ Subject
- View ≃ Observer
- Controller (what allows changing the state of the model, and choosing the desired view)

When the subject/model changes, all the views/observers registered with the subject/model, will be notified by the subject/model.